# How do I made a component reload/refresh from a seperate component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update a header component when a separate component adds an item to the shopping cart. I find lots of examples of doing a refresh on a button-click but nothing on calling from outside the component.

I have modified the header component so if I click the refresh button on my browser, the whole page reloads correctly. But now I need to have something in code to do it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Config from 'config';
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import { Jumbotron, Container } from 'reactstrap';
import { GetCount } from './ShoppingCart/CartHandler.js'

export function reload() {
    this.forceUpdate();
}

class LogoHeader extends React.Component {
    constructor({ history }) {
        super({ history });
        this.state = {
            name: 'React',
            apiData: [],
            canAdmin: false,
            history: history,
        };
    }    

    canAdmin() {
        console.log('Can Admin: ' + this.state.canAdmin)
        return this.state.canAdmin;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('app mounted');        
        
        const tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
        const token = JSON.parse(tokenString);
        this.setState({ canAdmin: token.canAdmin})

        fetch(Config.apiUrl + "/api/Header/GetLogo")
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ image: "data:image/png;base64," + data.image }, () => console.log(data)));

        fetch(Config.apiUrl + "/api/Header")
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => {
                sessionStorage.removeItem("header");
                sessionStorage.setItem("header", JSON.stringify(data));
                this.setState({ header: data }, () => console.log(data))
            });
    }


    render() {
        const logoImage = this.state.image;
        const myHeader = this.state.header;
        const count = GetCount();
        
        return (
            <div>
                <Helmet>
                    <title>{myHeader?.title}</title>
                </Helmet>
                <Jumbotron fluid>
                    <Container fluid id="headerContainer">
                        <img src={logoImage} id="logoImg" />
                        <input id="searchBar" type="text" placeholder="Search"></input>
                        {console.log('Location: ' + this.state.history.location.pathname)}
                        <NavLink to='/portal' isActive={() => this.canAdmin()}>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-person" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M8 8a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm2-3a2 2 0 1 1-4 0 2 2 0 0 1 4 0zm4 8c0 1-1 1-1 1H3s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4zm-1-.004c-.001-.246-.154-.986-.832-1.664C11.516 10.68 10.289 10 8 10c-2.29 0-3.516.68-4.168 1.332-.678.678-.83 1.418-.832 1.664h10z" />                            
                            </svg>
                        </NavLink>
                        <span>
                            {count === 0 ? null : '(' + count + ')'}
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-cart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M0 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 1H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 3H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .491.592l-1.5 8A.5.5 0 0 1 13 12H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.491-.408L2.01 3.607 1.61 2H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.102 4l1.313 7h8.17l1.313-7H3.102zM5 12a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm7 0a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-7 1a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z" />
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                    </Container>
                </Jumbotron>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
export default withRouter(LogoHeader);
```

I just want to add a count of items to show up besides the shopping cart icon.

As you can see, I tried adding a reload function. But I am getting an error that 'this' is undefined when I call it. I am unsure if this would ever even work. I only actually need the `<span>` part to refresh but I can't figure that out either. Any tips or help will definitely be appreciated.

Comment: ... why at all reload/refresh something ... if You need to "update" certain components, when action is "invoked" on another ... well, (if props' drilling isn't the best) read React State (global / app-wide) management ... Context Api, Redux, mobx or smt ...

Comment: I still cant figure out the problem your dealing with. There has to be some context that are missing. You said "I want to update a component when an item is added to the cart" the only part I understand.

Comment: @German When I add an item to the shopping cart in a separate component, I would like the header component to refresh. After  the comment  by Vovan_Super I am thinking I am trying to make React do something like C# does instead of how React is suppose to work. Ether way I am stuck.

Comment: @Randy when an item gets added from different component you would like to update the header component. let says if the count value is 0 then adding an item change it to 1 is that what you mean ?

Comment: @German the short answer Yes, but the header component still needs to update to reflect the change.

Comment: @Randy I thank you wanted to implement state management. If it so try to check this in codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-surf-zxnwv?file=/src/Header.jsx

Comment: @Vovan_Super I made this work with `State`, which was your suggestion first. Care to make your comment an answer?

Comment: @Randy, well, if you made it with setState and props-drilling - fine (bad idea, generally, but, if You feel like ok with it - have it), my suggestion is rather going with Context API (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) / Redux ... simple sample: https://github.com/VovanSuper/React-funky-notes/blob/master/src/context/notes/NotesProvider.js / https://github.com/VovanSuper/React-funky-notes/blob/master/src/App.jsx / https://github.com/VovanSuper/React-funky-notes/blob/master/src/components/Notes.jsx